# No frontend output of powermail form in gridelement - only cache-index

Tags: caching, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, powermail

I am using a powermail form inside of a two-column gridelement. While outside of the gridelement, the form works finde, but as I soon as I pack it into a column, it doesn't get rendered in the frontend.

Instead I just get a cache-reference (something like this: '< !--INT_SCRIPT.bac5b8b4bd3180848642d7849f -- >' ). So obviously the problem is somehow related to the content being cached.

So my question is: Where can I get started on fixing this?
How can I tell the gridelement to output rendered content instead of the cache-hash? Or would I need to get into the powermail code?

Here's my grid setup, in case that is any help:

```
plugin.tx_gridelements_pi1.setup.2col {

    outerWrap = <div class="row"> | </div>
    outerWrap.preCObject < lib.stdheader

    columns.default {
        outerWrap = <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> | </div>
        renderObj =< tt_content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check in witch order you include the static templates? Gridelements should be the last entry.
And do you have an output when you deleting the grid setup..?